# Extra m appears in com while working on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

[image]

Check the above image when I add any link my Google Sheet every time an extra m appears in the end of .com. How can I resolve this?

Comment: you gave us too little information to answer you ... try attaching a test file

Comment: ok allow me to elaborate , my problem is that when is write any website name in the cell of the google sheet for e.g stackoverflow.com and press enter than the text changes like this stackoverflow.comm automatically.

Comment: I understood this ,,, but if you attach the link to any file that presents that problem, MAYBE we can solve it

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ModuzJGRi8cgxc3NB6L0-lp-Zpo4HEAx/edit#gid=278250799  This is copy of the original spead sheet i am working as the original is the property of the company i am working for i cant share directly so i just changed the original data.

Comment: thanks ... but access to that file is denied ... authorize edit access